# Print a MS Project Gantt chart for each resource

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

I wonder if there is a function in MS Project to print the Gantt chart view for each resource, i.e., when issuing the schedule to everyone I print to PDF:

- Complete Schedule
- Summaries only
- Each Resources personal Gantt view

With around 10 resources it is quite momentous having to PDF them all when changes are made. Also since I need to do it each week... Maybe a UI script is needed here to take control... but they are rather tedious and need constant updating.

Comment: By a Personal Gantt view do you mean only seeing the tasks that that person is allocated to?

Comment: Yes exactly... and the groups they are under. I have been naughty and allocated the resource to the task headings which over allocates the resources which I may need to change. But when doing a filtered view for the resource they get to see the headings and their specific tasks for that task.

Answer (score 0):

just filter by resource and voila!

Comment: Yes I do that already. But I have to do it around 10 times, one for each resource and print it to pdf. This is so each resource can see what they need to do and when. I'm the only one with project, so everyone else only gets a PDF.

Comment: Basically I was formally a programmer and now I'm project managing and I'm lazy as for repetitive tasks and just want to have it all done from a click of a button. Light bulb... is there VBA or something for ms project....

Comment: Oh macros here I come. I will try and program it to be generic and post it if I ever get to doing it... the nature of a programmer is to spend lots of time to make simple momentous tasks quick.

Comment: Yeah, you can do it I a macro as well... Just record it and tweak it manually to get the best results.

Answer (score 0):

A VBA macro will do the trick.

Get personalized views, export to pdf and send by email to each one, with just a button click on your personalized toolbar.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example?